# Pandas group by time range and count elements by other column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a time series that contains one column with a date. The other colum has different and unique users and also locations.
group        user    location_more_visited
group1       u1       1
group2       u1       1

Tried to `groupby user, location and between_time(22:00, 07:00)`, but I cant filter after grouping, something like:

```
df.groupby(['user', 'location]).between_time(22:00, 07:00).max()
```

Any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

First, filter your dataframe to remove unwanted intervals then group by `user` and `time` interval. Finally, extract the most common visited `location`:

```
# Convert time as datetime64
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# Group by day with a lag of 2 hours: 24h - 2h = 22h, start of interval
time_grp = pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='time', offset='-2H')

out = df.loc[df['time'].dt.time.ge(time(22)) | df['time'].dt.time.lt(time(7))] \
        .groupby(['user', time_grp])['location'] \
        .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()) \
        .reset_index()
```

Output

```
>>> out
  user                time  location
0   u1 2022-02-15 22:00:00         1
1   u1 2022-02-16 22:00:00         1
```

Comment: Why is the lag of 2 hours?
Can you do it without defining time as index?

Comment: I updated my answer. Did you check it?